# How can I create a graphical Android Widget in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, android-widget

I developed an Android app - an analogue watch - with LibGDX and it works fine.
Now I would like to have the watch running as (or in) an android-widget. Is there any way to do this with LibGDX or is this just not possible? 
I don't want to do all the graphical work again under Android.

Comment: Not possible, Android widgets cannot use OpenGL, which is what LibGDX uses for rendering. You might consider making it a live wallpaper, which LibGDX can do.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour04. That explains why I couldn't find anything on this. I will try the wallpaper option. The disadvantage is that there is no interactivity, and that the user has to say goodbye to his former wallpaper.

Comment: Live wallpapers are interactive. You can use standard input events in Libgdx.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Interaction is indeed possible. I will start with the implementation asap.
Thanks again!

Comment: @Tenfour04, is this info still up to date? Did anything change in android since Jan 2016 that could be useful in making a homescreen widget? Or it still remains impossible?

Comment: @Raith As far as I know this has not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not possible because LibGDX uses OpenGL, which is not available to Android Widgets (thanks Tenfour04). Going for live wallpaper instead...